# Is there a way to query a Sqlite database outside of an app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to query the tables of the Sqlite database on the phone, but I want to do it from Windows. Is there some kind of manager that I can use to query the database?

For example, if I was using SqlServer, I could use sql server management studio to view & perform operations on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adb and Windows cmd for this if you're okay with using the cmd line. It's located in the platform-tools folder of the android sdk.

Open windows command prompt and navigate to the sdk\platform-tools folder

```
C:\sdk\platform-tools\ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ cd data/data/com.myapp/databases
shell@android:/ $ sqlite3 myapp.db
sqlite >
```

And now you can issue sql queries to the db.

You'll only be able to do this for the emulator, the db on a device is private and only accessible if the device was rooted

Answer (score 0):

There's good graphic tool available as firefox extension - [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). You can fetch sqlite database file from device/emulator with adb or DDMS.

Comment: for the english page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/